# HTML 5 Canvas drawing lines?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hi guys I have been comparing drawing lines on canvases between two different functions. I realise the lines drawn between the two functions are different but the code logic of the two functions seems to be exactly the same(to me).

The code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var radius = 10;
var dragging = false;


canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
context.lineWidth = radius*2;

var putPoint = function(e){
  if(dragging){
    context.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    context.stroke();
  }
}

var engage = function(e){
  dragging = true;
  putPoint(e);
}

var disengage = function(){
  dragging = false;
  context.beginPath();
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', engage);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', putPoint);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', disengage);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Canvas</title>
</head>
<body style="margin:0">
  <canvas style="display:block;" id="canvas">
    sorry this browser does not support HTML 5 Canvas!
  </canvas>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The line drawn from the above function:

[image]

If I modify the above function `putPoint()` to the following:

```js
var putPoint = function(e){
  if(dragging){
    context.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    context.stroke();
    
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);

  }
}
```

The line changes to this:

[image]

I don't understand why the two lines in any way should differ(even though it does).

```
var putPoint = function(e){
      if(dragging){
        context.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        context.stroke();
      }
    }
```

This function draws a much smoother line than the later as every time the function is called a line will be drawn from (x,y) of the previous function's coordinates to the (x,y) of the next functions's coordinates when it is called.

```
var putPoint = function(e){
      if(dragging){
        context.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        context.stroke();

        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);

      }
    }
```

This function appears to be the same to me as `moveTo(x,y)` would store the latest (x,y) coordinates. When `lineTo(x,y)` is called a line between the coordinates of `moveTo(x,y)` and `lineTo(x,y)` will be drawn. This seems to be exactly the same to me as the the first function although different lines are drawn.

Please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because in the second example the lines are not joined. The rending API has special code to fill in the gaps that are created when rendering thick curvy lines, by cheating lots od small paths you do not allow this code to do its thing.

**Controlling stroke rendering.**

You can control the line joining with the property `ctx.lineJoin` which can be `round`, `miter`, and 'bevel' if you use miter (pointy corners) you can control how far the mitering sticks out on sharp corners by setting the value of `ctx.miterLimit` to the number of pixels that it should not go past.

You can also control the line ends with `ctx.lineCap` property which can have on of `butt` ,`round`, and `square`  Butt has a flat end that stops at the coordinates of the start and end of the line. square add half the line width to the start and end of the line.

**Fixing the gaps**

To fix your line problem set the `ctx.lineCap = "round"` which adds a half circle to the start and end of each path segment. The circle is the same diameter as the line width. This will fill in the gaps you are seeing in the second line example.

Comment: Can you please explain with reference to moveTo and lineTo why the lines in the second example are not joined?

Comment: after lineTo(x,y) is called the function moveTo(x,y) stores the latest coordinates on the canvas. So when putPoint() is called again wouldn't the function lineTo(x,y) be connected to the latest coordinates from moveTo(x,y) fired from the previous putPoint() function?

Comment: MoveTo creates a gap in the path, even if the point is the end of the last path. moveTo is analogous to penUp move on a plotter, while lineTo is penDown and move. Because there is no join the render does not perform the code to fill in the joins with the method specified with `ctx.lineJoin` property

Comment: Ok, so ctx.lineJoin would connect the lines between each path segment? (connecting the empty spaces with a line)

Comment: No lineJoin tells the renderer how to join connected paths. Using MoveTo breaks the path and thus there is no join rendered. That is why you use the `ctx.lineCap = "round"` option. It does not join the lines from the render point of view, it just creates some overlap to hide the gaps. For most cases this works, but if you are using semi transparent stokes or transparent Composite operations you will get artifacts. If you wish to have the lines correctly rendered just redraw the complete path each time a new mouse sample comes in. (you will need to use offscreen buffer for the best result).